# Can we say that CSL has the same expressive power of PCTL?

Tags: logic, nonclassical-logic

In other words, a part from the fact that continuous stochastic logic (CSL) deals with continuous time models whereas probabilistic computation time logic (PCTL) deals with discrete time models, is there any difference between these two logics?